# Windows 11 firewall blocking port even though a rule allows the port

Tags: windows-11

I have a web server on a Windows 11 Pro PC running on port 12080. I can access http://localhost:12080 just fine, but can't access from any other PC on the same network.

I added a firewall rule allowing the inbound port of 12080 TCP for all three profiles (Domain, Private, and Public). No success. The firewall log for "Public" shows the packets are dropped:

2023-10-27 10:19:01 DROP TCP 192.168.195.114 192.168.195.142 60715 12080 52 S 2253698716 0 64240 - - - RECEIVE 16148

2023-10-27 10:19:01 DROP TCP 192.168.195.114 192.168.195.142 60716 12080 52 S 2119116775 0 64240 - - - RECEIVE 16148

2023-10-27 10:19:01 DROP TCP 192.168.195.114 192.168.195.142 60717 12080 52 S 3702646266 0 64240 - - - RECEIVE 16148

192.168.195.114 = Browser PC
192.168.195.142 = Web server PC

The firewall logs for Domain and Private show nothing.

I can Remote Desktop from the Browser PC to the Web PC, and ping the Web PC just fine. I just can't get to the web page. If I disable the firewall, the web page comes up just fine from any PC.

Thoughts?